# Action Bar изменение цвет при скролинге ListView

Tags: android

Подскажите, какое событие прослушать?

Есть listView с header'ом. У activty есть actionBar, но он полупрозрачный. На момент, когда часть header'a скрывается, нужно actionBar сделать красным.

Подскажите, какое событие прослушать?

P.S.: есть такой момент, в headere есть картинка, высоту её я  знаю. Вот когда эта картинка исчезает, нужно, чтобы ActionBar стал красным

```
contentListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (contentListView != null && contentListView.getChildAt(0) != null && actionBar != null){
                int p = contentListView.getChildAt(0).getTop() * (-1);
                int height = articleImageView.getMeasuredHeight();
                if (p >= height){
                    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0)));
                }else{

                }

            }

        }
    });
```

Пробую в этом месте, условие срабатывает, т.е. событие прослушать получилось. Но ActionBar цвет не меняет.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
getActionBar().getBackground().setColor(Color.RED);
```

И почитайте хабр на эту тему: [тык](http://habrahabr.ru/post/190102/)